# Loopback use a relation's remote method

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using loopback in my project and I have a MyUser model related (hasMany) to a SellerRequests model.

---

I see that I can now make a POST on /api/MyUsers/:id/sellerRequests to create a new sellerRequest linked to the user but what I want to do is to use this remote method in my common/my-user.js file.

I try to do a MyUser.__create__sellerRequests but this is undefined (same thing for MyUser.prototype.__create__sellerRequests and MyUser.createSellerRequests).
Any idea how to access the remote method ?

Thanks !

```
// here is my common/my-user.js file
module.exports = function(Myuser) { 
    console.log(Myuser.__create__sellerRequests); // This is undefined
}

// Here is my MyUser.json
{


"name": "MyUser",
  "base": "User",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "firstname": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastname": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "gender": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "birthday": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "spokenLanguages": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "phoneNumber": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "type": "date",
      "defaultfn": "now"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "sellers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Seller",
      "foreignKey": "customer_id"
    },
    "sellerRequests": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "SellerRequest",
      "foreignKey": "customer_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "patchAttributes"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "avatar"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "defaultAvatar"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "avatarUpload"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "avatarDelete"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "__create__sellerRequests"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "__destroyById__sellerRequests"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "__get__sellerRequests"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "__findById__sellerRequests"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Comment: What is your MyUser.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get user instance and use this

```
<user instance>.sellerRequests.create(data, function(error, result) {

});
```

where data is an object containing fields and values of `SellerRequest` model.

or use this

```
MyUser.sellerRequests({customer_id: <user_id>, <rest of the fields in seller requests>}, function(error, result) {

});
```

Reference: [Methods available to the model](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/HasMany+relations#HasManyrelations-Methodsaddedtothemodel).